# Samsung Galaxy S GTI-9003 spontaneously reboots

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

My Samsung Galaxy S GTI-9003 spontaneously reboots itself with different time intervals. The boot cycle does not complete and freezes at Samsung Logo.

When I take off the battery and switch it back on, all the data is gone, the phone is literally formatted.

I have tried several options like factory reset, changed the sim card, removed memory card but nothing is working.

Appreciate help from Enthusiasts

Comment: Sounds like a physical defect to me. Can you return it for warranty repair?

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with adb tools from the Android SDK? What you'll need is logging from your device as a starting point.

## The easy way

There are tools available (apk's) that can be installed from the Google Play store to read out the logcat. The 2 first hits on Google play look useful:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat

However this logcat is usually cleared on each reboot so that might not be your best option.

## The better way

More information will be retrieved using command line tools like adb from the google Android SDK.

### A quick step by step guide

- Download Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html (If you're not planning to develop go for the "Download for other platforms" > "SDK Tools Only" option on that page)
- Follow the installation instructions (download, extract)
- Have your android device connected to your computer using an USB cable (check if drivers are needed for your environment)
- Navigate to the `platform-tools` folder and execute the `adb` command with the following arguments:

  adb bugreport > bugreport.txt

That should create a `bugreport.txt` file within you current directory. Post that information here (**check for personal information first though**).

For more information about the adb tools check http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html